# Pass lists from one view to another in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to pass a `jlist` (which I generate everytime the 'javaindex' method is called) to another view i.e the `javaresult` view. I am generating the `jlist` from the `Question` model.

```py
def javaindex(request):
    javapool = list(Question.objects.all())
    random.shuffle(javapool)
    jlist = javapool[:10]
    request.session['jlist'] = jlist
    return render(request,'index.html',{'latest_question_list': jlist})
```

My other view is

```py
def javaresult(request):
    ch = [0]
    correct = 0
    jlist = request.session['jlist']
    for i in range(1,11):
        s = request.POST.get(str(i))
        if s:
            question, choice = s.split('-')
            ch.append(choice)
            if jlist[i].ans == ch[i]:
                correct+=1
    return HttpResponse(correct)
```

I searched on SO and hence added the `request.session['jlist']` but that is giving me an error `<Question: Question object> is not JSON serializable`.

How do i get rid of this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save ids of the Question objects in the session and get objects from DB in second view again.

```
def javaindex(request):
    ...
    request.session['jlist'] = [j.id for j in jlist]
    ...

def javaresult(request):
    ...
    jlist = Question.objects.filter(id__in=request.session['jlist'])
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for that :) It worked now. Just one small problem, the `jlist[i]` in result view is going out of bounds. Why is it so ?

Comment: @deveshasha - If you have another question you should raise it as a separate question complete with what you have tried and researched. If this answer has solved your issue you should consider accepting it

Comment: Because in `for i in range(1,11):` value of `i` is from 1 to 10, and in the last iteration when you do `if jlist[10].ans == ch[10]:` `jlist[10]` does not exist as jlist[9] is the last (10th) object. You need to use `i-1` as index.